# Unix - finding pattern in file matching given string

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Grettings
I want to see if a string has a regex match in a file

example :
file:

```
37|X|ari||ari????_test_V?|M|a.dat
38|Y|ari||FEB2016_ranstong_V?|M|x.dat
39|Z|ari||PA201606_outpop_V?|M|z.dat
```

string to search : `ari2014_test_V1`

result:

```
37|X|ari||ari????_test_V?|M|a.dat
```

any ideas ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ari2014_test_V1` is **not** matched by the regexp `ari????_test_V?`. Try `echo 'ari2014_test_V1' | grep 'ari????_test_V?'` and you'll see it produces no output. A BRE regexp that WOULD match `ari2014_test_V1` would be `ari...._test_V.` - is that what you meant to write or are you actually trying to use shell globbing patterns (where `?` matches a single character and `.` is literal) rather than regexps (where `.` matches a single character and `?` means zero or one occurrences of the preceding regexp segment)? It makes a big difference to the possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shell script:

```
kw='ari2014_test_V1'

while read -r; do
    IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$REPLY"
    for v in "${arr[@]}"; do
       [[ $kw == $v ]] && { echo "$REPLY"; break; }
    done
done < file

37|X|ari||ari????_test_V?|M|a.dat
```

Comment: That works for the sample data, but if the glob-style regexes included `*`, you'd need to map that to `.*` in the `awk` preprocessing step.  And maybe you'd need to map `[!a-z]` to `[^a-z]` for shell negated character classes.  These aren't required by the current sample data, though.